# Good books for romantic/contemporary period performance?

Tags: performing, books

Can anyone suggest me good books for improving knowledge (and performance) of 19th and 20th century music?

Comment: What instrument? Level? Country of origin?

Comment: Orchestral, opera genres. High level. Western world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Memoirs of Hector Berlioz.
Everyman's Library Edition is excellent.

This is an amazing book, not a history book, but a book that describes in vivid detail the emotions that inspired Berlioz's music, and gives a detailed account of what his life was like as a major composer in 19th century Europe. Most importantly, it is a very entertaining read.